# algorithm to add up objects in an array without mutating the original array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dictionary

I have an array of pending payments as objects and I want to know the total of all payments together as they are for the same shops. when the function is called once it calculates correctly, when I call it again it mutates the original array of objects.
I do not understand why it is mutating it when I am mapping over it.

I need the function to not mutate the original array of objects. It should do the calculation and just give me the result. Neither should it add on the current sum if it is called again. It should do it from scratch.

```
let pending = [ 
{Date: "20/12/2018",
Company:[ 
{Name: "Asda", Amount: 5.5},
{Name: "M&S", Amount: 10},
{Name: "Nisa", Amount: 15},
{Name: "Iceland", Amount: 10},
{Name: "Tesco", Amount: 5}
]},
{Date: "20/12/2018",
Company:[ 
{Name: "Asda", Amount: 5.5},
{Name: "M&S", Amount: 10},
{Name: "Nisa", Amount: 15},
{Name: "Iceland", Amount: 10},
{Name: "Tesco", Amount: 5}
]},
{Date: "20/12/2018",
Company:[ 
{Name: "Asda", Amount: 5.5},
{Name: "M&S", Amount: 10},
{Name: "Nisa", Amount: 15},
{Name: "Iceland", Amount: 10},
{Name: "Tesco", Amount: 5}
]},
{Date: "20/12/2018",
Company:[ 
{Name: "Asda", Amount: 5.5},
{Name: "M&S", Amount: 10},
{Name: "Nisa", Amount: 15},
{Name: "Iceland", Amount: 10},
{Name: "Tesco", Amount: 5}
]}
]

function returnSpendTotals() {
  let sumSpend = []
  let spendArray = pending.map(activities => activities.Company)
  spendArray.flat().forEach(spend => {
    let shopName = sumSpend.find(item => item.Name === spend.Name)
    if (shopName) {
      shopName.Amount += spend.Amount
    } else {
      sumSpend.push(spend)
    }
  })
  return sumSpend
}
```

it should return each time I call returnSpendTotals()

```
[{Name: "Asda", Amount: 22},
{Name: "M&S", Amount: 40},
{Name: "Nisa", Amount: 60},
{Name: "Iceland", Amount: 40},
{Name: "Tesco", Amount: 20}]
```

But if I call it a second time this is what I get

```
[{Name: "Asda", Amount: 38.5},
{Name: "M&S", Amount: 70},
{Name: "Nisa", Amount: 105},
{Name: "Iceland", Amount: 70},
{Name: "Tesco", Amount: 35}]
```

and pending first object is now

```
{Company: [
{Name: "Asda", Amount: 38.5},
{Name: "M&S", Amount: 70},
{Name: "Nisa", Amount: 105},
{Name: "Iceland", Amount: 70},
{Name: "Tesco", Amount: 35}],
Date: "20/12/2018"}
```

And the rest of the objects in pending are unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the destructured properties and build a new object for the result set, to prevent a same object reference to the used data.

```js
function returnSpendTotals() {
    return pending.reduce((r, { Company }) => {
        Company.forEach(({ Name, Amount }) => {
            let shop = r.find(item => item.Name === Name)
            if (shop) {
                shop.Amount += Amount;
            } else {
                r.push({ Name, Amount });
            }
        });
        return r;
    }, []);
}

let pending = [{ Date: "20/12/2018", Company: [{ Name: "Asda", Amount: 5.5 }, { Name: "M&S", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Nisa", Amount: 15 }, { Name: "Iceland", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Tesco", Amount: 5 }] }, { Date: "20/12/2018", Company: [{ Name: "Asda", Amount: 5.5 }, { Name: "M&S", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Nisa", Amount: 15 }, { Name: "Iceland", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Tesco", Amount: 5 }] }, { Date: "20/12/2018", Company: [{ Name: "Asda", Amount: 5.5 }, { Name: "M&S", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Nisa", Amount: 15 }, { Name: "Iceland", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Tesco", Amount: 5 }] }, { Date: "20/12/2018", Company: [{ Name: "Asda", Amount: 5.5 }, { Name: "M&S", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Nisa", Amount: 15 }, { Name: "Iceland", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Tesco", Amount: 5 }] }];

console.log(returnSpendTotals());
```

Comment: just for my understanding if you don't mind explaining. What was I doing wrong in the function that I wrote?
was this the problem line? let shopName = sumSpend.find(item => item.Name === spend.Name)

Comment: it was this part `sumSpend.push(spend)` where you took the object and added it to the result set **and** in combination with `shopName.Amount += spend.Amount`, where the inserted object gets an update, as well as the original data, which is unwanted. to separate the object reference, you could push a copy, like `sumSpend.push(Object.assign({}, spend));`.

Answer (score 1):

When you find a shop:

```
let shopName = sumSpend.find(item => item.Name === spend.Name)
```

you obtain a *reference* to an object that's part of your data structure. Your code then modifies that object:

```
      shopName.Amount += spend.Amount
```

I'm not sure exactly what to suggest as a fix because it's not completely clear what you're trying to do. Probably you should be keeping a separate running total instead of altering your "shop" objects.

Also note that the `.map()` process earlier in your function:

```
let spendArray = pending.map(activities => activities.Company)
```

similarly results in a list that's made up of references back into the original data structure.

Answer (score 1):

With this solution, it's just simple, it works, nothing fancy going on, just create an object, assign properties to that object, and iterate over the data object, that's it.

```js
const data=[{Date:"20/12/2018",Company:[{Name:"Asda",Amount:5.5},{Name:"M&S",Amount:10},{Name:"Nisa",Amount:15},{Name:"Iceland",Amount:10},{Name:"Tesco",Amount:5}]},{Date:"20/12/2018",Company:[{Name:"Asda",Amount:5.5},{Name:"M&S",Amount:10},{Name:"Nisa",Amount:15},{Name:"Iceland",Amount:10},{Name:"Tesco",Amount:5}]},{Date:"20/12/2018",Company:[{Name:"Asda",Amount:5.5},{Name:"M&S",Amount:10},{Name:"Nisa",Amount:15},{Name:"Iceland",Amount:10},{Name:"Tesco",Amount:5}]},{Date:"20/12/2018",Company:[{Name:"Asda",Amount:5.5},{Name:"M&S",Amount:10},{Name:"Nisa",Amount:15},{Name:"Iceland",Amount:10},{Name:"Tesco",Amount:5}]}];


const companies = {}; 


data.forEach(obj => obj.Company.forEach(o => {
  companies[o.Name] = companies[o.Name] == null ? 0 : companies[o.Name];
  companies[o.Name] += o.Amount;
}));


console.log(companies);
```

#### Edit

This one is pretty similar, only slightly more fancy... This is inspired by the answer from Nina Scholz, I am a fan of the syntax.

```js
const pending = [{ Date: "20/12/2018", Company: [{ Name: "Asda", Amount: 5.5 }, { Name: "M&S", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Nisa", Amount: 15 }, { Name: "Iceland", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Tesco", Amount: 5 }] }, { Date: "20/12/2018", Company: [{ Name: "Asda", Amount: 5.5 }, { Name: "M&S", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Nisa", Amount: 15 }, { Name: "Iceland", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Tesco", Amount: 5 }] }, { Date: "20/12/2018", Company: [{ Name: "Asda", Amount: 5.5 }, { Name: "M&S", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Nisa", Amount: 15 }, { Name: "Iceland", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Tesco", Amount: 5 }] }, { Date: "20/12/2018", Company: [{ Name: "Asda", Amount: 5.5 }, { Name: "M&S", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Nisa", Amount: 15 }, { Name: "Iceland", Amount: 10 }, { Name: "Tesco", Amount: 5 }] }];


const compelte = pending.reduce((r, { Company }) => {
  Company.forEach(({ Name, Amount }) => r[Name] == null ? r[Name] = 0 : r[Name] += Amount);
  return r;
}, {});


console.log(compelte);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function returnSpendTotals() {
  let companies = {}
  pending.forEach(item => {
      item.Company.forEach(company => {
          if (!companies[company.Name]) {
              companies[company.Name] = company.Amount;
          } else {
              companies[company.Name] += company.Amount;
          }
      })
  })
  return companies
}

returnSpendTotals(pending)

// result:  {Asda: 22, M&S: 40, Nisa: 60, Iceland: 40, Tesco: 20}
```